# What is the file location of GNOME favorites?

Tags: gnome-shell, menu

I want to directly inspect the contents of my GNOME favorites bar. What is the file location for this bar?

(Similar questions focus on creating custom `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`, setting the WM_CLASS, and pinning the running application. I am looking for direct access to the stored data.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`, the dconf database. You can’t edit that file directly, you need to use `gsettings` (for command-line access or use in scripts) or `dconf-editor`. The favourites are stored in `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`;

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

will show the current value, and `gsettings set` will allow you to change it.

The values stored are names of `.desktop` files. These can be found in `~/.local/share/applications` and in `applications` subdirectories of the entries in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` (*e.g.* `/usr/share/applications`).

Comment: I'd like to add that to set the value it must be one string. You should enclose the output of `get` into quotes ".