# Putting GNOME favorites in launcherbar

Tags: gnome, launcher

I want to put my favorites in the launcherbar to set each time to the same for one user only. The tutorial on [What is the file location of GNOME favorites?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405264/what-is-the-file-location-of-gnome-favorites?newreg=547404b304af44dba517fd1dd1945411) is very good.

The favorites that I want to set are :

```
['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop']
```

If the user changes the favorites, with a restart they must stand to the one above.

I've tried to give the command in the terminal to see if it works and it works splendid.

The command that works:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop']"
```

Who can help me? The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: those .desktop files have to exist in `.local/share/applications`, there is probably an XDG / FreeDesktop / GNOME specification about this somewhere